# How to define variable in Android if returned JSON variable has @ sign?

Tags: android, json, api

I am trying to use Retrofit to read json data from api,
but one variable inside the json looks like this; `@count`.
I have to define same variable name to receive data,
but this `@` sign violates the java naming rules.

So how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

Use count as variable name & @count as serialized name as

```
@SerializedName("@count")
public String count;
```

Use Gson for SerializedName feature

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
```